# .NET reflection : How do I invoke a method via reflection that returns array of objects?

Tags: .net, reflection

Had a quick question.. Googled but nothing worthwhile found..

I have a simple type like shown below.

```
public class DummyClass
{
    public string[] Greetings()
    {
         return new string[] { "Welcome", "Hello" };
    }
}
```

How can I invoke the "Greetings" method via reflection?  Note the method returns array of strings.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nothing special is required to invoke this kind of method:

```
object o = new DummyClass();

MethodInfo method = typeof(DummyClass).GetMethod("Greetings");
string[] a = (string[])method.Invoke(o, null);
```

Comment: Thanks, with var keyword this can be reduced to
var a = method.Invoke(0, null);

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code you need to call a method using reflection (keep in ind - the MethodInfo.Invoke method' return type is "Object"):

```
    DummyClass dummy = new DummyClass();

    MethodInfo theMethod = dummy.GetType().GetMethod("Greetings", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    if (theMethod != null)
    {
        string[] ret = (string[])theMethod.Invoke(dummy, null);
    }
```